# Using Java ruleSet properly

Tags: java, for-loop

Considering this piece of code

```
for (MyRule cr : crList) {    
  if (crIds.contains(cr.getParentId())) {
    ruleSet.add(cr);

    for (int cursor = 0; cursor < parentChildrenList.size(); cursor++) {
      if (parentChildrenList.get(cursor).getId().equals(cr.getParentId())) {
        parentChildrenList2.get(cursor).setChildRules(ruleSet);
        parentChildrenList2.remove(cursor + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  ruleSet.clear();
}
```

When I do the `ruleSet.clear()` I also lose the value I previously set in `parentChildrenList2.get(cursor).setChildRules(ruleSet);`

How can I stop losing it but in the same time clearing the `ruleSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `setChildRules()` (probably) doesn't create a copy of the `Set` referenced by `ruleSet`. It simply copies ("remembers") the reference to that `Set`. If you later *modify* that `Set` (such as calling `clear()`) then this will be visible to *everyone* who has a reference to that `Set`.

It *seems* like you want each element in `parentChildrenList2` to have *its own `Set`*. So you effectively need to replace `ruleSet.clear()` with `ruleSet = new HashSet()` (or whatever type you used).

Comment: Much appreciated. It works. Will mark as correct answer once I can.